# Need a TV/Movie API with associated trailers

Tags: api

Looking for a movie/TV API that offers previews (trailers), via widgets or links, as well.

I know IMDB has an API, but it only has metadata. Internet Video Archive also has an API, but, well, lets just say they seem a bit incompetent.

I could use YouTube, but I'd get a lot of cruft and unofficial results. Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet video archive: http://api.internetvideoarchive.com/

Comment: uhmm... isn't this a link to the same API (Internet Video Archive) mentioned in the question?